# NodeJs and JQuery: Path Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am building a file browser into an html page. This file browser is composed in JQuery and NodeJs with ExpressJs and DataTables. The issue at hand is that when a sub-directory directory is clicked, it is supposed to search and present files/directories in the clicked sub-directory; but, instead it searches and presents the files/directories of the original directory. The Directory in question is [AppName]/Public/Assets
}
Here is the html snippet:

```
 <body>
   <div class="panel panel-default mainpanel">
       <div class="panel-heading">
               Document Browser
               <span class="up">
                <i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> Back
               </span> 
        </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="linksholder" id="linksholder">
          <thead>

          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          </tr>

          </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable({
"fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
 if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
 var path = aData.Path;
 $(nRow).bind("click", function(e) {
  $.get('/files?path=' + path).then(function(data) {
    table.fnClearTable();
    table.fnAddData(data);
    currentPath = path;
  });
  e.preventDefault();
 });
},
 "aoColumns": [
      { "sTitle": "", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
          if (data.IsDirectory) {
            return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          } else {
            return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa " +  "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
          }
        }
      }
    ],
});
$.get('/files').then(function(data) {
table.fnClearTable();
table.fnAddData(data);
});
$(".up").bind("click", function(e){
if (!currentPath) return;
var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
var path =currentPath.substr(0, idx);
$.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
    table.fnClearTable();
    table.fnAddData(data);
    currentPath = path;
 });
});

});



    </script>
    </body>
```

}
Here is the expressJs snippet:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('lodash');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
 app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
 var currentDir =  __dirname + '/public/assets/';
 var query = req.query.path || '';
 if (query) currentDir = path.join(currentDir, query);
 console.log("browsing ", currentDir);
 fs.readdir('/[AppName]/public/assets', function (err, files) {
 if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  var data = [];
  files
  .forEach(function (file) {
    try {
            //console.log("processingile);
            var isDirectory = fs.statSync(path.join(currentDir,file)).isDirectory();
            if (isDirectory) {
              data.push({ Name : file, IsDirectory: true, Path : path.join(query, file)  });
            } else {
              var ext = path.extname(file);
              if(program.exclude && _.contains(program.exclude, ext)) {
                console.log("excluding file ", file);
                return;
              }       
              data.push({ Name : file, Ext : ext, IsDirectory: false, Path : path.join(query, file) });
            }

    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e); 
    }        

  });
  data = _.sortBy(data, function(f) { return f.Name });
  res.json(data);
 });
});
```

I know this is an issue with the path called on the call of function "fnCreatedRow", but I have tried to analyze and cannot pinpoint it. Here is output:

```
browsing  [AppName]/public/assets/:path
[ReferenceError: program is not defined]
 { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '[AppName]/public/assets/:path/1']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
   syscall: 'stat',
   path: '[AppName]/public/assets/:path/1' }
```

Where this is a file in the directory `[AppName]/public/assets` Not `[AppName]/public/assets/:path`

Comment: You can actually check http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/09/how-to-navigate-through-directories-in.html, where it is shown how to navigate through the directories and sub directories

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, however on the link you give the page has no content referring to navigate through directories and sub directories. However, I was able to do it after some searching. The problem is, that I have already made something to do this and I shan't throw it away. I am just having issues when calling a path, retrieving everything in that path.